# Start inappbrowser in a new activity android

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

i have to open an external link with cordova inappbrowser. The standard plugin works quite well but.. when it comes an heavy web page the app start to be lagging and sometimes it run out of memory.

I see that the plugin launch the webview in the same activity and its same Thread:

```
this.cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
            ....
      } 
}
```

It would be better if the inappbrowser would open in another Activity. How can i do this ?

Comment: why don't just open the links on the system browser with _system param?

Comment: Because i don't want that the user leave the app.

Comment: That's a good point. Right now it isn't possible, if you want to launch your own webview in a new activity you'll have to create your own activity with a webview and create a plugin that launchs that activity

Comment: But i can create a new cordova plugin that create a new activity ? What i want to avoid is to modify by hand the project created by cordova.

Comment: You have to create a plugin with 2 classes, one of them will be the plugin class (it has to to extend CordovaPlugin) and the other will be the new activity you launch (extends Activity). On the plugin install, it will have to declare the activity on the AndroidManifest.xml. Take a look into the QR reader or camera plugins, they launch a new activity from a plugin